# How to pass load a specific field of all documents from mongodb to memory in Java?

Tags: java, mongodb, nosql

I am now doing something with mongodb in the following manners:

1. Each document in Mongodb contains three fields: id, name1, name2.
2. Now I have a user input user_id
3. I search the whole collection in mongodb, to find the document with an id=user_id
4. return name1 and name2

So far my program in Java works, however, since there are many documents in a collection, and I make one query to each document for checking, it greatly reduces the performance. So my questions are:

1. Any advice I can improve (greatly) the performance?
2. I am thinking about loading all id from mongodb into memory as an arraylist, and compare them with user_id. When I find the matching one, I make only one query to the database and get name1 and name2. Any idea how to implement it in Java?

My current code is smth like below. Please kindly refer to it. Thanks!

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/{number}")
public Map<String, Object> getNames(@PathVariable("user_id") String number) {
     Map<String, Object> response = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
     Collection1 result = collection1Controller.getNumberDetails(user_id);
     if (result != null) {
        response.put(user_id, collection1.findOne(user_id));
     }
     else 
        response.put("Unknown", null);
        return response;
     }
}
```